# is there a way to provide iOS version check inside widget extension

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit, ios17

I tried to add iOS 17 version check inside WidgetBundle but the widget extension keep on crashing .

Getting `Thread 1: Swift runtime failure: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. After removing the iOS 17 check it works fine.

Is there any way to provide version check inside widgetBundle?

```
 struct MyWidgets: WidgetBundle {
        @WidgetBundleBuilder
        var body: some Widget {
            widget1()
            widget2()

            if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 16.1, *) {
               LiveActivity()
            }
            if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 17.0, *) {
               ContactdWidget()
            }
            
        }
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of how you are checking the version.

Comment: sure, I just updated the code

Comment: That is not a [mre]

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm facing the same problem with some crashes in Xcode organizer

Comment: you have split every possible version check in separate funtions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `WidgetBundleBuilder.buildBlock` for every separate version check and provide all supported widgets inside buildBlock for a particular version

```
struct MyWidgets: WidgetBundle {

    @WidgetBundleBuilder
    var body: some Widget {
        getWidgets()
    }

    private func getWidgets()-> some Widget{
        if #available(iOS 16.1, *){
          return getNewiOSWidgets()
        }else{
            //Older widgets
        }
    }

    @available(iOSApplicationExtension 16.1, *)
    private func getNewiOSWidgets()->some Widget{
        if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
            return WidgetBundleBuilder.buildBlock(
               Widget1(),
                Widget2(),
                LiveActivityWidget()
            )
        }else{
            return WidgetBundleBuilder.buildBlock(
                Widget3(),
                Widget4(),
                LiveActivityWidget()
            )
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem today. This is my solution

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI

@main
struct WidgetLauncher {
    // Combine widgets in this way to prevent crashes.
    static func main() {
        if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 17.0, *) {
            WidgetsBundle17.main()
        } else {
            WidgetsBundle16.main()
        }
    }
}


struct WidgetsBundle16: WidgetBundle {
    var body: some Widget {
        SomeWidget()
    }
}

@available(iOSApplicationExtension 17.0, *)
struct WidgetsBundle17: WidgetBundle {
    var body: some Widget {
        SomeWidget()
        Only17Widget()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach below works for me (updated):

```
@main
struct MyWidgets: WidgetBundle {
    
    @WidgetBundleBuilder
    var body: some Widget {
        widgets()
    }
    
    private func widgets() -> some Widget {
        if #available(iOS 17, *) {
            return WidgetBundleBuilder.buildBlock(Widget1(),
                                                  Widget2(),
                                                  LiveActivity(),
                                                  ContactdWidget())
        }

        if #available(iOS 16.1, *) {
            return WidgetBundleBuilder.buildBlock(Widget1(),
                                                  Widget2(),
                                                  LiveActivity())
        } else {
            return WidgetBundleBuilder.buildBlock(Widget1(),
                                                  Widget2())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to add check for ios17,ios16 and below